# How to set or get data from elasticache using aws-sdk methods

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-elasticache

I am trying get data from redis using aws-sdk in node js. so far I am able to connect with the cache using client-elasticache.

```
redisClient = new ElastiCacheClient({region : "REGION"});
```

Library : `@aws-sdk/client-elasticache`

But I am not able to find any direct method to get data from cache using this client for example **get()** or **mget()** we have in io-redis. Is there a way to get data like this using aws-sdk?

Answer (score 5):

The AWS SDK ElastiCache client is for managing ElastiCache servers. It is for performing tasks like creating or deleting entire servers or clusters.

You need to use [an actual Redis client library](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) for interacting with the data inside your Redis cluster.

Comment: Thank you for this simple clarification.   I wish I would have found it 4 hours ago.